# I use Hathaway as ISP. Can not login without internet explorer to LAN

Tags: networking, internet

I live in Bangalore India.

My ISP is Hathaway

On Windows Internet Explorer, my ISP redirects me first to their homepage and I need to login. After that I can use internet without any issues

But on Ubuntu I do not have IE. And it does not redirect with anything else

What can I do?

Comment: Have you tried Firefox or Chromium?

Comment: Good grief. How can one get HTTP-level redirecting so wrong that it only works in IE... This is a fault of your ISP. Bug them to get this fixed, really.

Comment: You should have a look at their interface. You will puke. No hopes man. No chance of improving at all. I took it because it was too cheap for the speed but then it comes as a package. Getting a wifi modem in a while. After that I do not have to bother at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that the server would not redirect me if I was not using IE

But it is resolved now. I got IP address that I had to go to directly to login